# how can I use multithreading to compute the intersection on a very large dataset

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, intersection

I have a file composed of 4 millions sets. every set contains 1 to n words. The size of the file is *120 MB.*

```
set1 = {w11, w12,...,w1i}
set2 = {w21, w22,...,w2j}
...
setm = {wm1, wm2,...,wmk}
```

---

I want to compute the intersection between all the sets.

```
Set 1 ∩ {set1,...,setm}
Set 2 ∩ {set1,...,setm}
...
Set m ∩ {set1,...,setm}
```

Every operation takes Around *1.2* seconds. What I did the following:

- divide the 4 million sets into 6 chunks. Every chunk containing *666666* sets

Then I do the following. In here i'll be creating 36 threads and i'll be computing the intersection between the chuncks. It is too slow and I complicated the problem.

```
 vector<thread> threads;
 for(int i = 0; i< chunk.size();i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < chunk.size();j++)
    {
       threads.push_back(thread(&Transform::call_intersection, this, ref(chunk[i]),ref(tmp[j]), chunk(results)));
    }
  }

for(auto &t : threads){ t.join(); }
```

---

Do you have an idea on how to divide the problem into sub-problems and then join all of them together in the end. any good way in linux too?

---

## Sample

The first column represents the ID of the set and the rest of the columns represents the words.

```
m.06fl3b|hadji|barbarella catton|haji catton|haji cat|haji
m.06flgy|estadio neza 86
m.06fm8g|emd gp39dc
m.0md41|pavees|barbarella catton
m.06fmg|round
m.01012g|hadji|fannin county windom town|windom
m.0101b|affray
```

---

### Example

m.06fl3b  has an intersection with m.01012g and m.0md41. The output file will be as follows:

```
 m.06fl3b m.01012g m.0md41
 m.06flgy
 m.06fm8g
 m.0md41 m.06fl3b
 m.06fmg
 m.01012g  m.06fl3b
 m.0101b
```

Comment: What is solution of Sample?

Comment: It's also unclear exactly *what* takes 1.2 seconds.  Surely not performing the intersection of 2 sets?  So, what then?

Comment: 1.2 seconds for a set VS all

Comment: I only keep the sets where there is an intersection i'll give u an example

Comment: SO NO I Don't need 16,000,000,000,000  FOR COLUMNS AND ROWS I took care of that GOT U

Comment: @LukaRahne in the solution I only keep the sets where these is only an intersection as you can see. So I wont be needing 4 million columns and 4 million rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set intersection is *associative* and therefore amenable to [parallel folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) (which is one of many use cases of [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)). For each pair of sets ((1, 2), (3, 4), ...), you can compute the intersection of each pair, and put the results into a new collection of sets, which will have half the size. Repeat until you're left with only one set. The total number of intersection operations will be equal to the number of sets minus one.

Launching millions of threads is going to bog down your machine, however, so you will probably want to use a *thread pool*: Make a number of threads that is close to the amount of CPU cores you have available, and create a list of *tasks*, where each task is two sets that are to be intersected. Each thread repeatedly checks the task list and grabs the first available task (make sure that you access the task list in a thread-safe manner).

Comment: The first part of the answer is really cool. concerning MAPREDUCE I was starting to look but seemed little complicated. 

Concerning the threads i didn't explain it correctly. I have 36 threads which is also huge lol

Comment: have you seen the output? I know that I have a very huge matrix. 4m x 4m So I have decided to keep just the sets where I have an intersection.

Comment: I misunderstood what you're trying to achieve. For each set, you want to figure out which sets overlap with (have a non-empty intersection with) that set? I hope you're using `unordered_set` or some other hashmap-like structure to represent each set, because that will make the intersection checks much faster. Also, you don't need to compute the full intersection for each set pair; you can stop whenever you find that there is at least one mutual word. I'm not sure about any other ways to optimize it, though.

Comment: (But you can halve the time by observing that intersections are also symmetric, so you only need to compute whether set _i_ intersects set _j_ for _i_ < _j_.)

Comment: Actually the sets are in vector<string> I'll use unordered_set

Comment: That should give a drastic speedup, as it takes expected _O(n)_ operations to check if a given element exists in a vector, versus expected _O(1)_ to check in a hashmap.

Comment: I was thinking. i'll be going with thread-pooling as you explained it's better. I 'll write the code and add it to the question later. IF you can check it later on today or tomorrow will be great

Comment: If you add another comment here when you've updated the question, I'll get a notification about it (not sure if I'll have time, though).